# flexbox center image in middle of screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys got a simple question, playing around with flexbox in bootstrap 3 and i cant seem to center my image in the middle of the screen, i got it so that its in the middle but right now its at the top of the screen rather then the center :

HTML:

```
    <div class="parallaxb">
            <div class="homeimgbarber">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/cuts.png" style="margin: auto;">
              </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.parallax {
    background-image: url("../img/c.png");
    min-height: 1000px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.homeimgbarber {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because .homeimgbarber needs height applied.

```css
.parallax {
    background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
    height: 1000px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.homeimgbarber {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
   <div class="parallaxb">
            <div class="homeimgbarber">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
              </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Anytime! Don't forget to accept this answer :) happy coding